# Import API webhooks not triggered

Tags: fusionauth

When I use the import API (/api/user/import) the webhooks are not triggerd.

I tested this using postman, the /api/user/registration endpoint is working.

This is the postman request resulting in no webhooks fired and 200OK:

```
  "users": [
    {
      "active": true,
      "birthDate": "1976-05-30",
      "data": {
        "displayName": "Jan"
      },
      "email": "jan@fusionauth.io",
      "encryptionScheme": "salted-md5",
      "factor": 1000,
      "password": "5ac152b6f8bdb8bb12959248d542cb237c4a730064bf88bbb8dd6e204912baad",
      "expiry": 1571786483322,
      "firstName": "Jan",
      "fullName": "Jan",
      "insertInstant": 1331449200000,
      "lastName": "Boos",
      "middleName": "Kleine kinderen",
      "mobilePhone": "303-555-1234",
      "passwordChangeRequired": false,
      "preferredLanguages": [
        "en",
        "fr"
      ],
      "registrations": [
        {
          "applicationId": "7a61c6e9-b1bb-44c0-8532-07af1b04674a",
          "data": {
            "birthplace": "Amsterdam"
          },
          "insertInstant": 1331449200000,
          "preferredLanguages": [
            "de"
          ],
          "username": "Jan",
          "verified": true
        }
      ],
      "salt": "NDdiYWZkZDMtYjk5ZC00ZmZkLWE1YmUtZTQxNGM4MDkwNWYw",
      "timezone": "America/Denver",
      "twoFactorEnabled": false,
      "usernameStatus": "ACTIVE",
      "username": "Jan",
      "verified": true
    }
  ]
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Where is your code? We need more information to answer.

Comment: I use this in postman and get a 200OK, no webhooks are fired and no errors are to be found in logs.

Comment: Does the Webhook tester work ? (Settings > Webhooks > Test)

Comment: @Robotdan yes it does.

Comment: You can also verify that the event is enabled in the Webhook (Settings > Webhooks > Edit > Events), and in the Tenant configuration. (Settings > Tenant > Edit> Webhooks). If both of those are enabled, please open a GitHub issue so we can further debug.

Answer (score 0):

It was a RTFM issue:
We selected our application on the Applications tab under webhooks settings.
We did not know selecting an application will limit you to only receiving application events.

You can still enable the events even if the are not fired, this is confusing from UX standpoints.

Solution: Selecting "All applications" in the configuration.